# How can I stop a second touch in the delay from firing?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I've got this jquery -

```
(function(){

jQuery(window).bind('touchstart', function(){
    $('#email-info').fadeOut('2400', function() {
    });  
});

jQuery(window).bind('touchend', function(){
    $('#email-info').delay('2800').fadeIn('2400', function() {
    });    
});

})();
```

Which works great, but if I touch my phone when it's in the 'delay' it'll fadein/out quickly again.

Is there a way to stop this ?

Comment: You could always put the touchend in the callback function so it can't fire until the animation is cmoplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).bind('touchend', function(){
    $('#email-info').delay('2800').stop(false,false).fadeIn('2400', function() {
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using `.stop()`

http://api.jquery.com/stop/